# Under what conditions this equation $F(x)=-c x^{n+p} - b x^n + (a-c)x^p -b =0$ has solutions?

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification

Let 
$$
F(x)=-c x^{n+p} - b x^n + (a-c)x^p -b
$$
where 
$$
(\mathscr{H})\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    x > 0, &  \\
    a >  c > 0, &  \\
    b > 0, &  \\
    0<p <1 &  p \in \mathbb R, \\
n\geq 2 & n \in \mathbb N.
  \end{array}\right.
$$
Kindly I would like to give answer to this question:

> Under what  conditions concerning the parameters 
>    $c$, $b$, $p$, and $n$
>    the equations $F(x)=0$, $x> 0$ 
>    admit a solution in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: You use the word "optimal", but you do you measure optimality ? And, prior to that, in presence of two solutions, what criteria permits to say that one is preferable to the other ? In my opinion, this word "optimal" should be cancelled..

Comment: There is a bigger problem: your inequations  $a<c, c<0$ and $a>0$ are  are non compatible !...

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's great and I have already modify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial result (with its proof):

a) if there are real positive roots, they are in interval $(0,x_0)$ with $x_0=\left(\frac{a-c}{c}\right)^{1/n}$.

b) a **necessary** condition for the existence of such roots is that $x_0^{p}>\dfrac{1}{a-c}$.

(Said otherwise, this necessary condition is $(a-c)^{n+p}>c^n$).

Proof: Let us write the equation under the form:

$$x^p=\dfrac{b(x^n+1)}{-cx^n+(a-c)} \ \ \ (1) $$

Now "think graphically" on $\mathbb{R}_+$. (see figure below) : formula (1) is verified by the abscissas of the intersection points (if they exist) of the two curves of

$$y=f_1(x)=x^p \ \ (2) \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \  \ \ y=f_2(x)=\dfrac{b(x^n+1)}{-cx^n+(a-c)} \ \ (3) $$

The curve of $f_1$ is increasing on  $\mathbb{R}^+$.

The curve of $f_2$ has, on $\mathbb{R}^+$:

- a vertical asymptote $x=x_0$ with $x_0=\left(\frac{a-c}{c}\right)^{1/n}>0$ and
- a horizontal asymptote $y=y_0$ with $y_0=-\frac{b}{c}<0$.

$f_2$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R_+}$ because its derivative $f'_2(x)=\dfrac{n a b x^{n-1}}{(c-a+c x^n)^2} $ is $> 0$ on $(0,+\infty)$.

Due to the horizontal asymptote, it is clear that no intersection can occur between the right branch of $f_2$ and the curve of $f_1$. Thus, if there are solutions $x \in \mathbb{R_+}$ of equation (1), they can only be in the interval: $0 \leq x \leq x_0$ therefore establishing point a).

Concerning the second point, if $f_1(x_0)<f_2(0)$ (which is equivalent to (*)), it is impossible for the curve of $f_1$ and the left branch of the curve of $f_2$ to intersect, due to the increasing property of $f_1$: this justifies point b).

Figure : a case with two roots: curves of $f_1$ (half parabola) and $f_2$ for $p=1/2,n=3,a=6,b=c=2$:
[image]